# Is there any way to get the Tezos binaries latest version?

Tags: node

How can I get the Tezos binaries of the latest version?

Answer (score 1):

For now, binaries are available through Docker:

- Official ones: https://hub.docker.com/r/tezos/tezos
- By Stove Labs: https://github.com/stove-labs/granary

Answer (score 1):

You can rebuild from sources using the latest head! It is preferred method if you intend on baking.

Always backup your existing binaries first though as protection.